# Draw bar chart on TextView background

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, draw

I have a ListView that contains a TextView as one of the items in the list items. The custom adapter extends ArrayAdapter. The TextView will contain names. I would also like to draw a simple bar chart under the text in the TextView background. It will represent monthly sales per salesperson. So it will have 12 vertical bars (one for each month) that proportionally span the width of the TextView (each bar is one-twelfth the width of the TextView).

What would be the proper way to go about doing this? I am relatively new to Java and Android; but have years of programming experience in other platforms just so you know the level of detail I am hoping to get. E.g. where would I implement the drawing code (in the getView() of the adapter?) and how to go about drawing simple bars on the background of the TextView? Thanks.

Comment: This is not possible, as a text view is just that, text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options, you could draw custom bars on a canvas. Then place your text view on top of it.

https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing

Or you could use something like MpAndroidChart to do the bar graph for you, then again, place your text view over it.

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Update:

Check out this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/advanced-android-training-create-canvas/index.html?index=..%2F..advanced-android-training#0) for custom drawing.

I would recommend doing something like this in a more powerful list, the [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview), you would populate your data when you bind your views to the recycler view. This would give you more runtime flexibility and efficiency to handle this custom scenario.

You could stack the views using a few different layout types but overlapping views is easiest in `FrameLayout`

```
<Whatever Your List Item Parent Layout Is

   <FrameLayout
          android:id="@+id/myListFram"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/my_image_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

     <TextView
            android:id="@+id/my_text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

   </FrameLayout>
</ Close Parent>
```

Check this out:
https://academy.realm.io/posts/360-andev-2017-joshua-lamson-custom-drawing-canvas/

Comment: Hi Richard. Thanks. I had found the developer documentation on custom-drawing, and that seems to be all I need to draw 12 simple bars. However, still I am confused about how one would go about 'placing the TextView in a ListView on top of the canvas'. Do I add the canvas view to my List_item.xml and somehow position it behind my TextView? Then draw on the canvas in the getView() method? Or what? Thanks.

Comment: Try breaking this down into some steps, create a recycler view that shows the text, overlap some views, draw.

Comment: Also, if this helps please accept it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Check out the link I updated. I think it will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks so much! A quick glance at it just now and it looks like want I need.